# Plot ROC curve using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

I tried to create an ROC curve with sklearn, below is my code

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
fpr_keras, tpr_keras, thresholds_keras = roc_curve(validation_generator.classes, y_pred_label_indices)
```

when I print

print(fpr_keras):

```
[0.    0.48  0.568 0.584 0.632 0.648 0.664 0.68  0.992 0.992 1.    1.   ]
```

print(tpr_keras)

```
[0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.016 0.016 1.   ]
```

print(thresholds_keras)

```
[2.0000000e+00 1.0000000e+00 9.9999988e-01 9.9999976e-01 9.9999893e-01
 9.9999881e-01 9.9999833e-01 9.9999821e-01 9.6940529e-01 6.8794215e-01
 5.7934558e-01 1.9927023e-05]
```

but when I plotted it using this code :

```
plt.plot(fpr_keras, tpr_keras, thresholds_keras)
plt.plot([0,1], [0,1], 'r--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
```

I got this :

[image]

why is that?, is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Add your results for 1st code as well

Comment: I added the printed value of each variable

Answer (score 0):

ROC curve is a plot of fpr and tpr only.
for ploting ROC curve you should just do this `plt.plot(fpr,tpr)`

However, with the data you provided, results are very bad for ROC curve.

Now, the plot that you have shown above is the result of

`plt.plot([0,1], [0,1], 'r--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])` only not an ROC curve

Try running both codes separately. You 'll get it.

Comment: any idea why the data resulting bad roc curve ?

Comment: It depends on True positive rate and false positive rate. If these both are not good enough, your ROC will be a bad curve. as the golden rule "Garbage in, Garbage out".